# Dictionary implementation that use name as key and birthday as value

Tags: c++

For this assignment, you will implement a dictionary to track the name and birthday of your friends and relatives.  You should be able to do the following operations:

- add an entry
- remove an entry
- search the dictionary for the birthday for a given name
- display the name and birthday of every entry in the dictionary
- list everyone in the dictionary who was born in a given month

  The search key is the name, and you may assume that the names are unique.

  for this assignment, i have already implement most of the class except the same birthday. this is what i m planning to do for my sameBirthday class.

  ```
  void Dict::sameBirthday()
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < itemcount; i++)
   {
          if(item[i].getDate() == item[i+1].getDate())
          {
              int index = i;
              cout << item[index].getName() << "\n";
          }

   } 
  }
  ```

  the test was not really clear so i just make a counter just to see how many i would get and it was only giving me 1 increment. and i suppose to get 3 because i have declare that 3 people have the same birthDate. for this class, the key is the name and store in order, the value is the birthdate that can be acquire by search for name

Appreciate the help.

Comment: "Feel like" implies you haven't actually tested it.  If that is the case, do that first.  Once you *have* tested it, you should be able to explain just what the problem is.

Comment: You could create a reverse mapping such as `std::map<Date, std::vector<std::string>> birthday_to_name_map`.  Then accessing a list of everyone with the same birthday is trivial.

Comment: Your code as currently written will only output the first of a pair of names who are stored in _adjacent elements_ in your data structure.  This might be close to being a solution if you store records ordered by birthdate.  But that seems unlikely.  You also have an edge-case where you access one element past the end of your data structure, which most likely will be undefined behaviour.

Comment: the test was not really clear so i just make a counter just to see how many i would get and it was only giving me 1 increment. and i suppose to get 3 because i have declare that 3 people have the same birthDate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! thanks to paddy. i have make a mistake that i just compare the value to see which one have the same value in the array without giving what value to look for.so from this i can just use the input value to list the keys that have the same value. thanks again paddy!!

```
 void Dict::sameMonth(string month)
 {

    for (int i = 0; i < itemcount; i++)
    {
        if (month == item[i].getMonth())
        {
            cout << item[i].getName()<< " - ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
```